# Any way to edit metadata of MKV files (without re-encoding)?

Tags: metadata, vlc, file-conversion

When watching a MKV file from the web in VLC, the title bar (see "#1" in image below) seems to be pulled from metadata, not the filename.

If you open the “Get Info” panel in VLC, you can change the title (“#2”) and then click “Save Metadata” (“#3”), but when the file is re-opened, the old information is shown.

I have not found any other Mac apps which can edit MKV metadata. Several offer to edit mp4 metadata, but that isn’t what I need.

[image: VLC annotated screenshot]

Answer (score 35):

I have found a way to do this using `mkvpropedit` which is part of [mkvtoolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download).

```
mkvpropedit "foo.mkv" -e info -s title="This Is The Title"
```

There is a GUI wrapper for this app and other Mac installation instructions [available at the official website](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html#macosx).

Answer (score 16):

The [`MKVToolNix`](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) GUI way:

1. From the menu choose header editor.

[image]

2. Open the `mkv` file.
3. Under `segment information` there is a `title` item, change title as you wish.

[image]

4. There is not a save button, use the main menu to save changes.

[image]

## macOS Version Support

Current versions of MKVToolNix require **macOS Mojave (10.14)** or newer, but earlier versions of MKVToolNix might work for previous versions of macOS/OS X.

> As of v42.0.0, MKVToolNix uses [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional),<sup>[a](https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/-/commit/ebf0ba5b6a4ad61b6c1b3a5a6fbd61c2d413437f)</sup> which requires macOS 10.14.<sup>[b](https://twitter.com/timur_audio/status/1184424350105161730)</sup>

**macOS High Sierra (10.13)** and **Sierra (10.12)** should run up to [v41.0.0 "Smarra" (2019-Dec-06)](https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix-old.html?dwl=MKVToolNix-41.0.0.dmg).

> As of v30.0.0, MKVToolNix uses [Qt 5.12](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/index.html),<sup>[c](https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/-/commit/b6393350ab8871b44f7760524dbdf75d7ad25895)</sup> which requires macOS 10.12.<sup>[d](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/supported-platforms.html#macos)</sup>

**OS X El Capitan (10.11)** should run up to [v29.0.0 "Like It Or Not" (2018-Dec-01)](https://www.fosshub.com/MKVToolNix-old.html?dwl=MKVToolNix-29.0.0.dmg).

> As of v26.0.0, the "README.macOS.txt" file states that it `works only with macOS 10.11 "El Capitan" or newer`<sup>[e](https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/-/commit/a1b193b5b96c333ae7ae1e3d703178393844f456)</sup> (although `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` and `LSMinimumSystemVersion` are still at `10.9`, so it *might* run in Yosemite 10.10 or Mavericks 10.9).

**OS X Yosemite (10.10)** and **Mavericks (10.9)** should run up to [v25.0.0 "Prog Noir" (2018-July-12)](https://mkvtoolnix.download/macos/MKVToolNix-25.0.0.dmg).

> As of v9.7.1-build4, [`MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.html) and [`LSMinimumSystemVersion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/lsminimumsystemversion) are set to `10.9`.<sup>[f](https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/-/commit/fbe41fa2022fc71347012b8b156bbf20fa1648d7)</sup>

**OS X Mountain Lion (10.8)** *might* run up to [v9.7.1-build2 "Pandemonium" (2016-Dec-27)](https://mkvtoolnix.download/macos/MKVToolNix-9.7.1-build4.dmg).

> As of v8.2.0, the "README.macOS.txt" file states that it `works only with Mac OS X 10.9 and higher`, although `LSMinimumSystemVersion` is still at `10.8.0`, so it *might* run in Mountain Lion 10.8.
>
> Furthermore, `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is not set, so it should target whatever OS version it was built in.<sup>[g](https://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-862/libstuff/macosx_deployment_target.c.auto.html)</sup>  As *v9.7.0-build2* and *v9.7.1-build2* were built in Sierra 10.12, they won't run in Yosemite 10.10 nor El Capitan 10.11 (although they will run in Mavericks 10.9 and Mountain Lion 10.8, which appear to ignore that restriction).  See the relevant discussion [here](https://gitlab.com/mbunkus/mkvtoolnix/-/issues/1840).

Comment: This works, but it's one at a time - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367737/batch-remove-mkv-titles-only-no-re-encode?noredirect=1&lq=1 for a bulk method.

Comment: Can confirm this works for one file at a time.

Comment: yes it is not suitable for bulk operation. Other answers already took care of that. This is for small works when you don't bother to check the cli params (`mkvpropedit --help
`).

Answer (score 14):

As an addition one could use [`mkvpropedit`](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvpropedit.html) in a bash script to set the title of all mkv files in a directory. (Given the filename is the desired title.)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# This script takes all mkv files in the current directory and sets the filename
# (without .mkv) as its title in metadata

for mkvfile in *.mkv; do
    mkvpropedit "$mkvfile" -e info -s title="${mkvfile%.mkv}"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Just open the file in VLC player, Ctrl+I, choose the desired Metadata, title etc, change and then in the bottom, click 'Save Data'. That's all.

No other external editor is needed.

Comment: That is in the OP. He said it didn't work.

Comment: I tried this using VLC on a mac and it works. You just have to be sure to click the "Save Metadata" button in the Media Information window. It's not the easiest thing to find.

Comment: I think what may happen is if you change it, it will save, but if you just delete it, it doesn't.

Comment: @Tetsujin is correct, if you enter an empty value it will not accept it, it will look like it's working but when you check again the old value is still there, so it's easy to assume it "doesn't work", and in a way I guess it doesn't. In short, you can't delete, just change to something else.

Comment: It does not work, even if you click "save metadata". At first glance it seems to work, but once you reopen the file again in VLC you see the old value is still present. Tested with MKV file.

Comment: Yeah, as @user643011 said, it doesn't work on VLC (currently using version 3.0.11.1 on MacOS Big Sur). It appears to work, but once you reopen the file, it still shows the old info.

Comment: Tested on Windows, this doesn't change the metadata even if you "Save Metadata"

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded a looot of files, many of which had some *** in it's title, as an extension of another [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/273021/339939) made my own script.

It changes title for all `.mkv` files in directory (and it's subdirectories) while asking for an appropriate action. Actions are "Keep the name?[ 1] / Type a new name?[ 2] / Use the filename as a movie name?[ 3]".

Might update it later on [github](https://github.com/SLCH/bash-scripts/blob/master/movies/mkvRenameInFolders.sh), here's what there is for now:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script takes all mkv files in the (sub)directory and sets it's Movie name/Title
# Requires mkvtools (mkvpropedit) and mediainfo installed
#
# param1 Starting directory (defaults to current)
# param2 Default action to do with files
# (Keep the name?[1] / Type a new name?[2] / Use the filename as a movie name?[3])
# Be carefaul with param2 since this script doesn't (atm) back up the existing movie names.

IFS=$'\n'; set -f

updateTitle() {
    mkvpropedit "${1}" -e info -s title="${2}"
    echo "✅ Updated to \"${2}\"";
}

getMovieTitle() {
    echo "$(mediainfo ${1} | grep "Movie name" | sed 's/^.*: //')";
}

parseFilename() {
    filename=${1##*/}
    filename=${filename%.*}
    echo ${filename}
}

chooseAction() {
    f="${1}"
    curFilename="${2}"
    defaultAction="${3}"

    if [[ -n "${defaultAction}" ]]; then
        ans="${defaultAction}"
    else
        read -p "Keep the name?[1] / Type a new name?[2] / Use the filename as a movie name?[3] : " -n 1 ans
        echo
    fi

    case "${ans}" in

    1)
        echo "Keeping the old name"
        ;;
    2)
        read -p "New movie name: " newName
        updateTitle ${f} ${newName}
        ;;
    3)
        updateTitle ${f} ${curFilename}
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Invalid char \"${ans}\""
        chooseAction $@
        ;;
    esac
    echo
}

renameMovies() {
    for f in $(find ${1} -name '*.mkv'); do
        curTitle="$(getMovieTitle ${f})"
        curFilename="$(parseFilename ${f})"

        echo "File location - ${f}"
        echo "File name     - ${curFilename}"
        echo "Movie name    - ${curTitle}"

        chooseAction ${f} ${curFilename} ${2}
    done
    echo "Done"

}

renameMovies ${1:-$(pwd)} ${2}

unset IFS; set +f
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using windows I made a command prompt alternative that changes the titles of all Matroska videos to the filename.

```
REM This batch script changes the title segment information to the name of the file. 
REM The script only selects mkv files in the current directory

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s *.mkv') do (mkvpropedit.exe "%%~nxa" -e info -s title="%%~na")
```

Comment: This site is for Apple specific software and hardware - so it is expected that questions refer to macOS only unless they explicitly say otherwise. This question actually asks for Mac apps so it is not only an assumption