# Batch-remove mkv titles only, no re-encode

Tags: terminal, automator, video, encoding

Prompted by the answer to [Any way to edit metadata of MKV files (without re-encoding)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219699/any-way-to-edit-metadata-of-mkv-files-without-re-encoding) it appears I should be able to do this with `mkvpropedit`, part of MKVToolNix.

**TL:DR**
All I want to do is remove **any** title, so VLC tells me the show title & episode number, as listed in the filename - not who helpfully ripped it so I didn't have to rip all my own DVDs. I don't even have a DVD player in the TV room any more, I'm putting it all on a Mac Pro.

I've tried doing this in the GUI of MKVToolNix but it seems I can only do one file at a time & I have dozens.
My intention would be to be able to save something as perhaps a script/automator applet, to make it drag & drop in future, see if I've missed some option in the GUI editor that would let me batch edit, or indeed find another tool which is capable of batch editing.

Essentially, this is what I'm trying to achieve, just not one at a time…

[image]

Per comments, app contents…

[image]

<sup>Edited to remove early guesswork, no longer needed</sup>

Comment: Can you look into the .app to check whether the command line version is part of the bundle?

Comment: @nohillside - I'm not sure how to tell - image of app contents posted into question. Let me know if you need more.

Comment: The files between mime and platforms look like binaries. Try to run them from Terminal as `/Applications/MKV*37*/Contents/MacOS/mkvpropedit`.

Comment: @nohillside - I've managed to get something working. Bit of a hack, but success. I'll post what I've got so far, but I won't accept it yet, & see if anyone can improve on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was a bit unsure about trying a Java GUI app add-on for this, but I got it going reasonably easily.

Linked from MKVToolNix's [GUIs and batch operations](https://mkvtoolnix.download/links.html) page I found [JMkvpropedit](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=163753)

I couldn't initially persuade it to see the `mkvpropedit` binary inside MKVToolNix, either from its own file-picker dialog, drag & drop or even editing the file path [it won't edit or paste], so like a true newbie, I just copied it out of the app's 'Show Contents' into my Apps folder - tadaah! Now it can find it & use it.

After that it was simple.
Drag set of files onto the Input tab.
On the General tab, check Title & add `{file_name}`
Click Process files.
Done in seconds.

[image]

Comment: Nice find! I can see that's gonna come in handy! :)

Comment: @Monomeeth - Thank you! I did struggle a bit getting it to find the binary, but my 'newbie guess' seems to work well enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

To remove the title tag from every mkv file in a directory run

```
cd to/directory/with/mkv/files
for i in *; do mkvpropedit -d title "$i"; done
```

in Terminal.

Comment: `mkvpropedit` doesn't seem to be available on macOS by default. Can you add some details on how to install it?