# Extract audio from bluray/DVD to get spatial audio / surround?

Tags: itunes, audio, software-recommendation

I have over the years bought several concerts on bluray and DVD and I have traditionally converted them into MP3 files landing in iTunes to listen to on my iPhone.  Now I've found that my AirPods support spatial sound which I was wondering if it would make a more immersed experience if I reconverted those with surround sound using appropriate software.

What encoding should I use for this and what would be a good way to get this given say a MKV corresponding to the physical disk?

Comment: Do you see VOB files on those DVDs?  I haven’t ripped blu-ray, but I have extracted DVD audio

Comment: VLC can do this. There's a long explanation at https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Extract_audio/ which my eyes glazed over about 1/3 the way through ;) Ideally, you want to extract as AC3 which I think you will need to encapsulate in M4A to get it to play easily.

Comment: There's also mkvtoolnix - a hideously complex command line app with a Mac GUI front end which I use just to change the video title on screen [I've never gone any deeper into it than that;) There's a mind-numbing guide at https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvextract.html but also this is how I set up the GUI on Mac; which wasn't really all that obvious to me at the start - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367743/85275

Comment: @allan I have used handbrake and makemkv so far which handled these for me.

Comment: @Tetsujin I’m fine with a complex command line (they can usually be scripted) so I’ll have a closer look.

Comment: Wish you luck :)

Comment: Ok…so just to confirm, Handbrake was able to rip a BR disk?

Comment: @Allan Yes, using the makemkv libraries.

Comment: According to https://www.whathifi.com/advice/what-is-apple-spatial-audio it appears that "Apple spatial audio takes 5.1, 7.1 and Dolby Atmos signals..." and Handbrake by default downmixes to Dolby Prologic.   Worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found by experimentation that the simplest way to get movie mp4 with spatial sound was to use a surround preset in Handbrake.

Still experimenting on how to convert to audio-only but perhaps in the Windows version of iTunes.